# Call stored procedure in Spring3+ibatis without using mapping file

Tags: spring, ibatis

I have an application in which I am using Spring3 and ibatis. In my application I am using different spring annotation for select, delete, update etc. queries. Now I want to call a store procedure using spring annotation. I am not using an ibatis mapping file in my application. Then how can I call this store procedure in my program? My procedure is also returning the temp_table also.

I am also trying below code but it does not working..

```
@Select(value = "{call wfm_task_display(${processId}, ${locationId})}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@Results(value = {
        @org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Result
        (property = "field1", column = "field1"),
        @org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Result
        (property = "field2", column = "field2")})
```

Any suggestion?